# TypeScript errors in PHPStorm when importing Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, phpstorm

I would like to write TypeScript and I am using the PHPStorm 8.0.3 IDE on Windows.  I think the TypeScript compiler is correctly installed (if I type vanilla JavaScript into a .ts file, it is automatically compiled into .js, and if I set types in my declarations the IDE makes use of them).

I am trying to learn Angular 2, so I created a `main.ts` file with the following contents:

```
/// <reference path="angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

My folder structure:
main.ts
/angular2
__angular2.js
__angular2.d.ts

The IDE throws the following error on the first line (at `///`): `statement expected` (this error disappears if I delete the 2nd line). On the second line the errors include `expression statement is not assignment or call` and `expecting new line or semi-colon` (after `from` keyword)

Unlike WebStorm, PHPStorm settings does not have a TypeScript section under "Languages and Frameworks" subheader, but from within the IDE's JavaScript Libraries settings, I installed `angular2-DefinitelyTyped` with global scope.

note: annotations such as `@Component({selector: 'my-app'})` also make the IDE report an error (red squiggly underline) .

What am I missing?

Comment: The lines you mentioned make use of Typescript 1.5 .  PHPStorm/WebStorm does not fully understand TypeScript 1.5 yet, but WebStorm 10 has some limited 1.5 support. (For what it's worth, I have been disappointed with PHPStorm/IntelliJ's support for TypeScript overall, Visual Studio Community/Code is a lot smarter in that regard.)

Comment: @Dcoder I've been using PHPStorm so far because I am learning to code PHP, JavaScript, HTML and CSS and it supports all those well. Does your feedback mean that if you had to write a web application you would use several IDEs on the same project? (eg: Visual Studio Code for TypeScript and PHPStorm for others)

Comment: Yes, I use exactly this setup at work: IntelliJ as the main IDE, Visual Studio Community (waiting for TS 1.5 to get out of beta before I switch to Code) for TypeScript.

Comment: *"Unlike WebStorm, PHPStorm settings does not have a TypeScript section under "Languages and Frameworks" subheader,"* That's because in PhpStorm it's only available since v9 (to be released later this month). You can [try EAP build right now](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program).

Comment: Angular2 will have [better support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14690) in [WebStorm v11](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11206#comment=27-1027027) (not sure in what PhpStorm version it will be available yet, possibly v9.x or even v10).